# SenchaTouch 2 textfield with custom Model class

Tags: object, custom-controls, sencha-touch-2

I'm new with Sencha Touch 2. I'm trying to create textfields with custom Model:

```
Ext.define('EGenDocMobile.custom.Polje', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    config: {
        title:'Value',
        idProperty: 'Value',
        fields: [
            { name: 'Visible', type: 'boolean' },
            { name: 'Value', type: 'string' }
         ]
    }
});
```

Got my data from ext.list, and passed out to another View, now i'm trying to use Value string in fields

```
{
    xtype: 'textfield',
    name: '{FirstField.Value}',
    label: 'Ključ interna',
    readOnly: true
}
```

Can not use it this way... the only half-working method is if I use 
`name: 'FirstField',`

but then, texfields get value: `[object Object]`

what to call to get object.Value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way of doing that dynamically. You need to get an instance of your model (which is called a *record*) and then use that to update the field.

```
var field = Ext.create('Ext.field.Text', {
    name: record.get('Value')
});
```

Or if the field already exists:

```
field.setName(record.get('Value'));
```

Comment: Model has fileds of type:
` { name: 'Field1', type: 'TestApp.custom.Polje' },`

and "Polje" has items Value and Visible...
so if i use record.get('Field1') I will also get [object Object]...

.get() function dosen't work anymore on that object...